# .Rdata workspace saving in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, I save my workspace images for different projects (not R projects) as .Rdata files in many different directory locations associated with those projects. The .Rdata files will have a unique prefix that indicates the relevant project/analyses etc. I see that when I set Rstudio to save .Rdata on exit as the default it creates a new .Rdata file in whatever the default working directory is.

My question is this: If I begin in Rstudio by loading a particular .Rdata file is it the case that I have to 'save as' each time I want to resave that particular workspace image? In other words, the default save .Rdata in Rstudio does NOT save the loaded workspace image in the relevant directory with that file name. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct, although it is more a generic R behavior than due to Rstudio. R will attempt on shutdown to save an “anonymous “ .Rdata file unless you tell it not to. (I usually tell it “no”). I think you might be able to change that in your options settings.

Comment: So indeed, for unique .RData files, I will have to basically save as (using the session drop down) and over-write the previous .RData file (assuming changes to the workspace were made)?

Comment: A better idea:  don't do this.  When you work on a project, start with a fresh/empty Global Environment and then run the code associated with that project to re-create the necessary objects.

Comment: Yes, I do this regardless with saved scripts associated with the projects, but I do find having the data already loaded (rather than running code to reload the objects) is preferable since it preserves whatever data transformations I left off with etc.